# Is there any division between the RSF and the Sudan military besides a purely political one?

Tags: civil-war, sudan

The fighting (I guess we can call it civil war by now) [has been](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Sudan_(2023)) going strong in Sudan for months now, between the RSF and the army. Besides having different leaders etc., which I'm sure all want power, is there any other line of division between the RSF and the army? Like ethnic or religious, the latter at least in terms of intensity, e.g. is the RSF more Islamist than the army?

I've done a bit of reading on this, but I'm still utterly confused. On one hand, the RSF [appears](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/11/16/africa/sudan-investigation-rsf-enslavement-intl-cmd/index.html) to enslave people in some kind of ([Islamic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56289/did-an-egyptian-dean-of-islamic-studies-say-we-have-the-right-to-enslave-israel) or maybe just tribal?) tradition. On the other hand, the RSF [says](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/jun/19/sudan-paramilitary-group-rsf-boasts-of-detaining-islamists) *they* are fighting against radical Islamists, allegedly prevalent among the  regular military.

Comment: BTW, there's a somewhat interesting post [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/180ztr7/comment/ka9a8ev/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) making some strong claims about the RSF being racist/tribal in away that they consider themselves superior to 90% of the Sudanese and "50% of the force being foreign fighters recruited from Western Africa from one Arab tribe spread across" etc. It's pretty upvoted there, but probably not enough (right now) to turn it into a Skeptics question.