# Is rape and sexual assault a part of IDF's ideology or do they oppose it?

Tags: israel, 2023-israel-hamas-war, war-crime

There is mounting evidence of sexual violence carried out by the Israeli Defence Force against Palestinian women and children. Evidence points to the violence being perpetrated both pre- and post-October the 7th, and both in Gaza and the West Bank. In relation to the ongoing assault on Gaza, the UN has release [a report expressing concern that Palestinian women have been raped and threatened with sexual assault](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2024/02/israelopt-un-experts-appalled-reported-human-rights-violations-against).

Regarding pre-October the 7th, there are [many similarly shocking reports](https://electronicintifada.net/blogs/tamara-nassar/palestinian-child-says-he-was-raped-israeli-interrogator). A 15 year old boy reported:

> The boy said that the same individual [an IDF soldier] “knocked him to the floor while
> blindfolded and raped him with an object,” according to DCIP. The
> individual threatened to continue with the sexual violence until the
> boy confessed.

A [B'tselem report](https://www.btselem.org/torture/201308_etzion) details many instances of Palestinian detainees being threatened with rape and sexual assault. There is the case of an IDF soldier who [raped a Palestinian woman](https://www.timesofisrael.com/idf-officer-who-raped-palestinian-was-not-dismissed-for-earlier-sexual-offenses/) who needed a permit to work in Israel. There are many other references and examples. I have added some of them at the end to avoid making this question too long.

Given this body of proof, is there any evidence that this a policy by the IDF to terrorise the Palestinian population, or are these the actions of rogue members of the Israeli Defence Force? There is some evidence for the former, given that chief rabbi of the IDF, Eyal Krim, has suggested that [rape of gentiles during war is permitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyal_Krim). I am wondering whether there is any stronger evidence?

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/idf-sexual-abuse-palestine-gaza-b2498888.html

https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/war-gaza-un-experts-appalled-reports-rape-and-sexual-assault-palestinian-women-and-girls

Comment: Before anyone states that this should be closed as a 'push' question, let me note that we have a [similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82725/is-mutilation-sexual-assault-and-kidnappings-of-minors-a-part-of-hamas-ideolog) about the Hamas which a mod left open. The main difference between this question and that, is that my question is far better referenced.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point to this Q. The official answer of the IDF is going to be self-evident. Less officially, see Italian Philosophers comment to the other Q: "how likely are we to hear info from credible, unbiased sources?" And yeah, one can always find some--perhaps high-up--official who is going to says something that resembles collective punishment, but you know "terrorise" is going to argued 5-ways-to-heaven as maybe not being exactly the same thing. Etc.

Comment: Please avoid asking "whatabout" questions.  That is, questions directly inspired by some other question that you consider to be biased, in which you change the actors to those from the other side, with the intention of "balance".  For example if one person has asked "Is Trump racist", then don't ask "Is Biden racist".  This only causes discussion and argument.

Comment: The link you posted already answers the question.  It's a push question because you clearly are not interested in finding anything out.  The link already says that the IDF soldier is in prison for rape.  That answers the question.

Comment: @RadicallyReasonable, that is a single instance. Anyway, the Israeli judiciary and the IDF are not the same.

Comment: @BenCohen Deny it all you want, but it's clear evidence that this is a push question.

Comment: Clearly a push question. The previous question was predicated on widely-supported reports of the body performing the act, and an absence of opposition to such acts. This question is predicated on only the first question. If I ask if an arsonist disregards the life of victims, a question of whether the police disregard the life of said victims is silly.

Comment: This question would be better without a list of links to claims by victims, or at the very least not calling them "proof".  That's not to say that those events didn't happen, just that someone claiming it happened or someone reporting that someone claimed it happened is hearsay, not proof.

Comment: @Bobson, I have linked to a UN report and a B'tselem report. That is pretty strong evidence.

Comment: The best form of whataboutism would be to be up front about it. Pretending this question isn't such a thing is intellectually dishonest. What about ism isn't a great thing however you dress it, though.

Comment: @BenCohen You've linked to a UN press release which is full of words like "reportedly" and "allegations", and the (15 year old) B'Tselem report is much the same.  That makes them _allegations_ of assault, not _proof_.  A consistent pattern of allegations is a good indication that there's something going on that should be investigated, but it's still not proof.

Answer (score 7):

While there are widespread reports of some sexual assaults by the IDF, there has been no reports of widespread policy of or support for such assaults.

The IDF has a history of prosecuting sexual assaults. While there are likely cases that haven't been prosecuted, this does make it clear the IDF as an organization opposes sexual assault.

As for a public statement, “Israel remains ready to investigate any concrete claims of misconduct by its security forces when presented with credible allegations and evidence.” - https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.cnn.com/cnn/2024/02/20/middleeast/israel-hamas-un-investigation-sexual-abuse-intl/index.html

IDF forces regularly have civilian Palestinians under their power. In the vast majority of cases, no sexual assault is claimed.

There appears to be serious problems, with crimes happening. I wish the IDF would do more. That doesn't make the situation comparable to Oct 7.

Comment: From the article you linked though, the case doesn't seem that strong "Even in the few cases in which testimonies were collected about sexual offenses committed on October 7, police failed to connect the acts with the victims who were harmed by them." I get it though that many of the suspected victims are probably dead.